# Unable to find value for employeeId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using microsoft graph api through the SDK in a C# application. But I am unable to see any values for employeeId field that is there in the beta version as shown below :
[Microsoft Graph API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjP3h.png)

We are trying to filter the users based on a specific value of employee ID.
When querying through powershell, the value shows up :
[Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOKN9.png)

I also checked the extended properties on Graph API Explorer, but the employeeId property doesn't show up there.

I expect Microsoft Graph API And Windows Graph API To be inline with each other. But clearly, that is not the case here.

Please help!

Thanks,
Yogesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your app to access data in Microsoft Graph, the user or administrator must grant it the correct permissions via a consent process. I guess you're only using the **User.Read** permission, this is only limited to return basic information. You might try to allow **User.Read.All** permission which required an Admin Consent.

This link might be helpful:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#user-permissions

Comment: Thanks @cedgabrang. That was the issue basically. We are using application registration and application permissions instead of delegate permissions to read active directory resources. As soon as I provided my application registration the User.Read.All permission and consented it through the admin, I was able to read the required fields.